# How to get an array of selected <option> values in a Table <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 10 columns

[image]

I am trying to loop through the NAME row to get the 4 selected names from the dropdowns.

I used to only need one, but had to add 3 more. I get one by this code

```
 var $tds = $(this).find('td').filter(':visible')
                name = $tds.eq(0).children().val()
```

I just can't work it out... GONE blank.

Any code or help would be appreciated.

Happy Holidays

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `.map`

```
var vals = $tds.eq(0).children('select').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyxuscfj/)

Comment: You should filter using children('select') instead of children() , else you would also get the value of any other html tag within that td.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each `select` in the first `td` cell using `$.each()`. To get to the correct selector, you may use `:first` instead of `eq(0)`.

```
var arr = [];
$('td:visible:first select').each(function()
{
  arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/rv3wwpsf/1/

UPDATE : To find all select values in all rows :

```
var arr = [];
$('tr').each(function()
{ 
   $(this).find('td:visible:first select').each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).val());
  });
});

alert(arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/rv3wwpsf/2/

Comment: That works great. I have another row below with 4 more and it is not finding those.

Comment: updated the code and fiddle. Follow the section in UPDATE

Comment: In my code, it shows all 12 values 3 times.
What I mean is I have 3 rows of 4 selects (so my image in the question * 3
I need to get them in groups of 4 so I can send the four to a DB and then get the next four, etc
Make sense?

Comment: Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/rv3wwpsf/5/ . If you still have issues, you might need to post the html you are working with